# Windows 10, can ping other PC but cannot access shared folders! What gives?

Tags: networking, windows-10, network-shares, file-sharing, shared-folders

I have a computer running Windows 7 that shares a Git repo on drive D. Let's call this PC "`win7`". This repo is the origin of a project that we push to and pull from.

The network is a wireless network. One PC on this network is running on Windows 10. Let's call this PC "`win10`". `Win10` can ping every other PC on the network including `win7`. `Win7` can ping `win10`. `Win7` can access all shared files on `win10`. Neither of the PCs have passwords.

**Problem**: `Win10` cannot access any shared files on `win7`, not from Explorer, nor from Git Bash or any other Git management system (E-Git on Eclipse or Visual Studio). So, `win10` cannot pull/push. Every other PC on the network can access `win7` shared files and push/pull to/from the shared Git origin.

What's wrong with Windows 10?

I have tried these:

1. Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings\ File sharing is on, Discovery is on, Password protected sharing is off
2. Adapter Settings\Properties\QoS Packet Scheduler uninstalled and re-installed
3. Adapter Settings\Properties\File and Printer Sharing uninstalled and re-installed
4. Adapter Settings\Properties\EVERYTHING uninstalled and re-installed
5. gpedit.msc\Computer Config\Win Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options:

   **Enabled These:**

   - Network access: Allow anonymous SID/name translation
   - Network access: Let Everyone permissions apply to anonymous users

   **Disabled These:**

   - Network access: Restrict anonymous access to Named Pipes and Shares
   - Network access: Do not allow anonymous enumeration of SAM accounts
   - Network access: Do not allow anonymous enumeration of SAM accounts and shares
6. `netsh int ip reset`, and then restarted
7. `netsh winsock reset`, and then restarted
8. AdapterSettings\ Enabled NetBIOS over TCP/IP
9. Tried changing to static IP
10. The new windows 10 Control Panel\ Network Reset
11. Firewall is turned off

All of these were tried to no avail.

Comment: So what have you tried to enable file sharing on the Windows 7 machine? Have you tried HomeGroup yet?

Comment: Are the user names and passwords the same between the computers?

Comment: You haven't told us exactly what *happens* when you try to access Win7 from Win10. Do you get an error?

Comment: @Sonickyle27 Edited the question

Comment: @AllenHoward Neither of the PCs have Passwords.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Error Code 70080035, The network path was not found

Comment: @MostafaZeinali do you get the same error if you access win 7 by its IP address, e.g. `\\ipaddress\sharename`?

Comment: What's result using IP addree and hostname of Win7? Compare their ipconfig /all output to make sure their Node Type are the same.

Comment: Also please turn off the security software include the Firewall temporarily to see if it's caused by port blocked.

Comment: @KarenHu Access through \\ip is the same as \\name which is Error code 70080035

Comment: @KarenHu All firewalls were turned off!

Comment: OK... I'm about to re-install windows. Does anybody have ANY ideas other than those I've already tried?

Comment: @MostafaZeinali are the user names the same?

Comment: @AllenHoward No, they are very much different;

Comment: Okay guys, I reinstalled windows, any new suggestions wont be testable. So, Should I close this question or leave it open?!

Comment: Windows file sharing in a workgroup setting is a bit odd-- normally the user names and passwords need to be the same between both computers, otherwise things don't work.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

AT LAAST!! After 4 month, and seeing the error for the second time, I found the solution here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4046019

Turns out, if you type the ip in "Run", and only in "Run", a very specific error shows up that contains this message: "your organization's security policies blocks access..."

Searching that lead me to this solution:

Open "Local Group Policy Editor" by searching in Start Menu or going to Run and running `gpedit.msc`, then go to `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\network\Lanman Workstation` and:
"Enable insecure guest logons"

And that solved the problem.

Comment: Isn't this the same as "Turn off password-protected sharing"?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/psYm79w.png

Comment: Unfortunately, and speaking from two times experience with this problem, no, in both times the password protected sharing was turned off.

Comment: I would say, if you ever ran into this problem and password protected sharing was already turned off, pay the ol "Lanman" a visit :)

Comment: Could you please elaborate how you got access to `Computer configuration\administrative templates\network\Lanman Workstation` . Have exact same issue after win10 crash

Comment: Nvm, run gpedit.msc and follow your instructions...

Comment: @Nightwolf Thanks, added clarification to the answer.

Comment: I've tried other solutions,but didn't worked,but this solution was perfect.

Comment: I also had to do the following, but finally got it to work:
`sc.exe config lanmanworkstation depend= bowser/mrxsmb10/mrxsmb20/nsi`
`sc.exe config mrxsmb10 start= auto`
and restarting the Workstation (lanmanworkstation ) service