# Networking Issues After Updating to Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, file-sharing, wired

I recently updated two computers from Windows 7 to Windows 10 that were on the same wired network and worked just fine. After the update, computer A and B can see both computers on the network. Computer A can ping and access files on computer B but computer B can't do either of those things. When I try to access data on computer A from computer B, I get an error that says:

> file and print sharing resource is online but isn't responding to connection attempts
>
> The remote computer isn't responding to connections on port 445, possibly due to firewall or security policy settings, or because it might be temporarily unavailable. Windows couldn't find any problems with the firewall on your computer

Both computers are only using Windows Defender for security at the moment. I tried creating rules computer A for allowing traffic on port `445` to no avail. These are also my file sharing settings on both computers:

[General Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzIXo.jpg)
[Guest or Public](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OETQG.jpg)
[All Networks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCZ3b.jpg)

Both computers are in the same workgroup and of course, I also set the files and folders I'd like to share between both computers to be shared with everyone. Any suggestions for fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I do is make a user on Computer A that is the user name and password as Computer B. Make sure the files / folders you wish to see on Computer A are shared to this new user on Computer A. This greatly facilitates sharing between computers.

Separately and as an aside, some upgrades from Windows 7 to 10 do not go well. We have seen this numerous times. Do a Windows 10 Repair Install using the Microsoft Media Creation link.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button, select Save.
Create a USB Windows Installation key and then run Setup on the USB Key. 
This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Answer (score 0):

I hate it when I see these types of "solutions" to these questions. But I turned on computer B this morning and I'm suddenly able to access computer A. Maybe an update was installed or configured when I last shut it off and didn't realize? I have no idea otherwise. However, if other people are looking at this later, I did find an interesting and potential solution [here](https://superuser.com/a/1326327/1093435) that I hadn't seen elsewhere. Thanks!