# I can ping but I can't access to shared folder

Tags: windows-10, windows-xp, network-shares, file-sharing, shared-folders

I've two machines one with XP OS and the other with win10.

they can see each other via ping command because they are connected to the same domaine.

the problem is when I share a folder on the xp machine I can access to it in win10 machine but the reverse does not work !

I verify the Network and Sharing Center advanced options, everything is turned on, also no firewall nor anti-virus is activated ! I try to check all PCs available in the domaine on my xp machine, my win10 machine not present in the list

I tried the solution given [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1287731/windows-10-can-ping-other-pc-but-cannot-access-shared-folders-what-gives) but no way !

Comment: did you try [this configuration](https://tinyapps.org/blog/201805170700_winxp_to_win10_folder_share.html)?